# How to display a field collection as a responsive table?

Tags: views, entities, theming

I'm using *field collection* and *field collection table* modules to show the data as a table, but I want that the table is be responsive.

How I do it? I don't found a good solution.

For example, for views table I use [responsive_table_filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables_filter) that accomplishes this task.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a good solution for displaying tabular data in a responsive way. Even big organizations like Wikipedia, Google, and GitHub display tables as horizontally scrollable entities.

If you can think of a way to display tabular data legibly with variable width, be sure to publish it. :)

Comment: Sure but for responsive I mean that when the windows is resized the flow of the tabular data changes.
For example, for views table I use responsive_table_filter module that accomplishes this task.  https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables_filter